Как убрать индексы в Pandas?
Создадим файл data.csv и запишем туда:
name,age
John,20
Paul,25
Kate,23

Я хочу вывести на экран эту таблицу. Мой код:
import pandas as pd

Data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
Data.to_string(index=False)
print(Data)

Вывод:
   name  age
0  John   20
1  Paul   25
2  Kate   23

Как мне убрать первый столбик (индексы 0, 1, 2)?

Чтобы корректно вывести содержимое DataFrame без индексов, вам нужно присвоить результат метода to_string(index=False) какой-то переменной или сразу передать его в print(). В вашем коде результат вызова to_string(index=False) не используется, из-за чего индексы всё равно отображаются при печати Data. Измените последние две строки вашего кода следующим образом:
import pandas as pd

Data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
formatted_data = Data.to_string(index=False)
print(formatted_data)


Data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
print(Data.to_string(index=False))

Так выводит без индексов

